# Need help on debugging calloc related error, minimal code attached

Tags: c

I want to allocate an array dynamically in one function, load the obtained memory with data, and then free it in the calling function. Is there a glaring mistake in the following code?
Thanks for your time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void tf(int** ptr);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int *arr;
    tf(&arr);
    free(arr);    
}

void tf(int** ptr)
{    
    *ptr = (int *) calloc(2, sizeof(int));
    if(*ptr!=NULL)
    {
        *ptr[0]=10; 
        *ptr[1]=20;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `(int *) calloc( .. ` instead `*ptr = calloc(2, sizeof(**ptr));`.

Comment: Please tell us what is the problem

Comment: So.. what is the error?

Answer (score 2):

The glaring mistake is the assignment of `20` beyond the end of `ptr`. (on x86_64) The reason has to do with *operator precedence* in C. When you pass the address of `arr` to `tf` for allocation and to initialize values, you cannot simply assign

```
    *ptr[0]=10; 
    *ptr[1]=20;
```

(well, you can assign `*ptr[0]=10;` but only because the index of `0` no possibility or *pointer* / `type` mismatch. However, `*ptr[1]=20;` is beyond the end of your allocated memory, again on x86_64)

Why? Answer: *operator precedence*. If you look at the operator precedence table, you will see that `[]` has higher precedence than the `*` (dereference) operator:

```
                C Operator Precedence

Priority   Operators                                Associativity

(high)      () [] . ->  (postfix)++  (postfix)--       l -> r

  ^         ++(prefix)  --(prefix)                     r -> l
  |         !  ~ sizeof(type) +(unary)
  |         -(unary)  &(address)
  |         *(dereference)
<snip>
(low)
```

What occurs with `*ptr[1]` according to precedence is the `ptr[1]` index is applied (moving the address to the second element of `ptr` (by `sizeof *ptr` bytes), which since you only allocated `8-bytes` (two `int`s on x86/x86_64) `ptr` is will be an address outside of your allocation on x86_64) Then the *dereference* operator is applied in attempt to change the value at that address.

Why is `ptr[1]` outside of the allocation? (here is the insidious nature of the issue -- it depends...) Consider an x86_64 machine. On x86_64 an `int` is `4-bytes` and a *pointer* is `8-bytes`. You allocate for 2 `int` or `8-bytes`. What is `ptr`? It is a *pointer to pointer to int*. How many bytes does `ptr[1]` advance? `8-bytes` (by `sizeof *ptr`). So on x86_64, you are attempting to assign `4-bytes` of `20` to an address `1-byte` beyond the end of `ptr` (which has bytes `0-7` allocated). Now on x86, both a *pointer* and `int` are `4-bytes` (so you are safe by accident, even if wrong -- only by virtue of a pointer and `int` being the *same size*).

How do you fix it? By surrounding the dereference of `ptr` in parenthesis, e.g. `(*ptr)` so now by rules of precedence the, look at the table above again, `()` applies before `[]`, meaning the dereference for `(*ptr)` occurs before `[1]` giving you the proper pointer address (which is a *pointer to int* -- which advances by `4-bytes` instead of `8` on x86_64.)

So bottom line, if working with the *address of* an array, you must dereference within parenthesis before applying the index to avoid the *pointer* / `type` mismatch which will occur otherwise.

Think through this and let me know if you have any questions. As for your approach to dynamic allocation (other than the operator precedence issue), it is up to you whether you pass the *address of* or whether you declare `ptr` within `tf` and return a pointer for assignment in the calling function.

Your `tf` could be written as follows:

```
/* allocate memory for 'ptr' using address of 'ptr' */
void tf (int **ptr)
{    
    *ptr = calloc (2, sizeof **ptr);
    if (!*ptr) {
        fprintf (stderr, "tf() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    (*ptr)[0] = 10; 
    (*ptr)[1] = 20;
}
```

Or as discussed in the previous answer now deleted, you could simply declare `ptr` within `tf` (we'll call it `tf2`) and return the value for assignment, e.g.

```
/* allocate memory for 'ptr' and return for assignment */
int *tf2 ()
{
    int *ptr = calloc (2, sizeof *ptr);

    if (ptr) {
        ptr[0] = 30; 
        ptr[1] = 40;
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

Then in `main`

```
arr = tf2();
```

(you will validate `arr` in main following the call to `tf2` and assignment of the return in this case)

There are other ways to do that as well. In fact you can combine both methods above and have the convenience of either passing the address or assigning the return available. Again, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your time in detailing the explanation. I appreciate that a lot. Although the fine details that you have pointed out are very relevant and did not occur to me, operator precedence did. I found that with a pointer to a pointer to an array, one can assign values in (at least) the following three ways:

```
void tf(int** ptr)
{    
    *ptr =  (int*) calloc(3, sizeof(int));
    if(*ptr!=NULL)
    {
        (*ptr)[0]=10; (*ptr)[1]=20; (*ptr)[2]=30;
        *(*ptr)=10; *(*ptr+1)=20; *(*ptr+2)=30; 
        ptr[0][0]=10; ptr[0][1]=20; ptr[0][2]=30;
    }
}
```

Actually, I will generally do what you have indicated for a single pointer if thats the only entity to compute and report, however, here I only posted a minimal snippet that was causing the problem. The context is that I am reading a sparse matrix's CSR arrays from disk, whereby the read function that I wrote is supposed to first calloc space, then write the various arrays at the addresses passed as input arguments. 
Once more, thanks a lot for your help and the time taken to elaborate.